# Upside down screen on Pi with Kumantech 3.5"

Tags: touchscreen, raspbian-stretch, screen, lcd

On a pi B with raspbian-stretch, I have tried every tip I could find to get the touch screen to rotate 180 degrees: commands in `config.txt`, new drivers, using `./LCD-show 180`, and more. Nothing works except modifying the config command to `Dtoverlay=tft35a:rotate=270`.

However the touch functionality doesn't rotate along with the display.

Can anybody offer me a solution or, worst case, suggest a case that incorporates the display with the usb and ethernet ports on the right? I bought the very nice Astroprint case that puts the screen at a 45 degree angle.

Answer (score 1):

Add to config.txt:

```
lcd_rotate=3
```

This is presuming the LCD is attached by DSI ribbon cable. That should also rotate the touch coordinates too.
1 = 90°
2 = 180°
3 = 270°

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=166959

Comment: The display sits right on the GPIO connector, so this doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think the touch part of the screen behaves as a different part (a input device) on top ot the display's output device. So you have currently just rotate the latter not the input

[This](http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-touchscreen-calibration-screen-rotation/) suggest a similar concept - except the screen is rotated by adding this to `/boot/cmdline.txt` (you may be able to stick with your existing rotation command, in which case some of these options may need to be different!):

```
fbtft_device.rotate=X
```

To actually change the touchscreen orientation, try changing `swap_xy=0` to `swap_xy=1` in `/etc/modules` (on the `ads7846_device` line).

Then follow by running `sudo apt-get -y install xinput evtest`, and adding this line:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xinput --set-prop 'ADS7846 Touchscreen' 'Evdev Axis Inversion' 1 0
```

before the `. /etc/X11/Xsession` line in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`, and rebooting.

Again, you will lily require different parameters (it also suggests `0 1` at the end of the `DISPLAY` line).

These devices are general purposes when you have got the rotation working, it should help to calibrate the touch-screen as well! - this is also detailed in [that article](http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-touchscreen-calibration-screen-rotation/).

Comment: Thanks and I read the article. Unfortunately the screen doesn't rotate, and there is no ADS line in 'modules' to change. There is only a single unrelated parameter.

Comment: @AndyF (probably should of checked this in the first place, it usually helps to provide this...) what system image and touchscreen model & version are you using?

Comment: Using Raspbian-stretch, Kumantech 3.5", RPI version. Supposedly, I need to re-calibrate the touch and modify /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf with the coordinates, but that doesn't seem to work.